# How to check whether google ad has been set in application?

Tags: google-ads-api, ads

Now we have a feature. Add google advertisement in application. If google ad has been set, then show the `div` area. Otherwise, remove the `div` area(not show ad space). But how to know google ad has been set?

We can prepare the google ad script as below:

## Header

```
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
    var googletag = googletag || {};
    googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];

    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.defineSlot('/[ID]/[NAME]', [[WIDTH, HEIGHT]], '[CONTAINER]').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
        googletag.enableServices();
    });
</script>
```

## Body

```
<div id='[CONTAINER]'>
    <script>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('[CONTAINER]'); });
    </script>
</div>
```

How to check the response data?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood *google ad has been set* means *ad slot has been filled by an ad*. If not please refine your question. 
Answering your question:

Check out [googletag.events.SlotRenderEndedEvent](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletageventsslotonloadevent)

> This event is fired when the creative code is injected into a slot.
>   This event will occur before the creative's resources are fetched, so
>   the creative may not be visible yet. The event is fired by the service
>   that rendered the slot

In the callback you'll also have a flag indicating if the slot [has been filled or not](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.events.SlotRenderEndedEvent_isEmpty)

> isEmpty - true if no ad was returned for the slot, false otherwise.

Although you can do it programmatically, also take a closer look at [collapseEmptyDivs(opt_collapseBeforeAdFetch)](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_collapseEmptyDivs):

> Whether to collapse the slots even before the ads are fetched. This
>   parameter is optional; if not provided, false will be used as the
>   default value.